# Is there a centralized Java libraries repository such like CPAN for Perl?

Tags: java, maven, module, open-source, cpan

People build repositories of software (like these that contains GNU/Linux packages) or  code, documentation, all centralized in one place.

All modules/libraries installations can be done through it. Re-using code is a good thing, and it helps developers to not reinvent the wheel, debugging existing code and share the work with others. Using a system like this one, you will retrieve security-updates easily. It helps to develop the community too.

CPAN is a good example of a large and comprehensive ecosystem, and it is become [a strength of the Perl language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cpan#Influence).

I would like to know if a similar thing exists for the Java world and what are the main differences from the Perl/CPAN world (I don't try to open an opinion based debate but hope for constructive discussion). I've heard about a [Maven's Central Repository](http://search.maven.org/) but if Maven provides "*patterns to a project's build infrastructure in order to promote comprehension and productivity by providing a clear path in the use of best practices*", is it also largely used to promote publishing of Open Source code?

I would like to know what kinds of tools are used today and what are your experiences around this problematic.

Comment: Voted to close as this is an opinion based question. In Java Maven is a way to go with a central repository.

Comment: I don't think it's an opinion, it is well known that one of the most [useful thing in Perl is CPAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cpan#Influence). I've asked with CPAN because I've used it a lot, but if you prefer, I could say Node.js's npm, PHP's PEAR, Python's PyPi, Ruby's Gems or even GNU/Linux package managers. I will update my question because it seems to be confusing.

Comment: http://mvnrepository.com/

Comment: This question is already worded to not solicit opinions. He asks what repositories exist, not which ones are "good".

Comment: It was a mistake to close the question. Right now I am trying to find out whether java has something like cpan, gems, pypy etc.. and google sent me here; and now I still (!) don't know the answer. I assume that java does not have something like this, but now I have to google more - please do not close questions because you think it is "off-topic". IMO it is hugely relevant to people who try to FIND the answer to that question, besides the fact that I do not consider this to be off-topic at all whatsoever. It sure enough IS a related question to java. People want to distribute their code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maven is the way to go !

It has plugins for eclipse, and other IDE's plus it supports a decent building process.

Check this out: http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/

Comment: +1 And just to add re:documentation, Maven central contains the JavaDocs of most jars uploaded there. So your IDE can display JavaDoc documentation (CTRL-Q or CMD-J in Intellij) for most classes/jars obtained from there.